# Profile Pictures Disappeared. Mystery here - GAE (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

Ok, first I want to state that this is Google App Engine via Python.

Any who,

These are my handlers / routing where the problem is occuring. Please read below for context and specifics:

```
class GetImage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        img = db.get(self.request.get("entity_id"))
        self.response.out.write(img.image)

class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, profile_name):
        current_user = str(self.user.name)
        profile_name = current_user
        if self.user:
            key='ag5kZXZ-c3VpdGVnYW1lcnINCxIHSW1hZ2VkYhgxDA'
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Imagedb WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key() # this is the key
            self.render('profile.html', profile_name = self.user.name, current_user = self.user.name, profile_image = key ,username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, first_name = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country, prov_state = self.user.prov_state, city_town = self.user.city_town)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')

class Change_Profile_Image(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            self.render('change_profile_image.html', username = self.user.name, firstname=self.user.first_name, current_user = self.user.name)
        else:
            self.render('change_profile_image.html')

    def post(self):
        imagedb = Imagedb(name = self.user.name)
        imageupl = images.resize(self.request.get("img"), 200, 200)
        imagedb.image = db.Blob(imageupl)
        imagedb.put()
        self.redirect('/profile/'+self.user.name)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/register', Register),
                               ('/article', ArticlePage),
                               ('/profile/([^/]+)', Profile),
                               ('/login', Login),
                               ('/logout', Logout),
                               ('/welcome', Unit3Welcome),
                   ('/games', Games),
                   ('/forum', Forum),
                   ('/media', Media),
                   ('/rank', Rank),
                   ('/review', Reviews),
                   ('/events', Events),
                               ('/alreadyloggedin', AlreadyLoggedIn),
                   ('/change_profile_image', Change_Profile_Image),
                               ('/img', GetImage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Alright so here is where stuff gets loopy. If I change the Profile class to take -- get(self) and remove my reg expression from the routing for the profile class, my images work perfectly. As soon as I route to unique profiles, i.e. pass profile_name into the Profile handler and map the URL to that profile, I lose all functionality of my GetImage handler. When I look at the source code, nothing has changed. The image is still being passed into the template as per usual.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on here? I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance. Hopefully my knowledge will catch up to you guys and I'll be answering questions soon :p.

Comment: "Ok, first I want to state that this is Google App Engine via Python." - as long as you tag your question correctly (which you have!), there's no need for a preamble like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing a (simplified) version of your template.

There are also a couple of weird elements in your code that make it hard to tell what's going on. It's hard to format this as a comment, so I'm putting it as an answer, just so you can at least see it.

- In your `get` request in your profile handler, you try to get the current user *before* you  check that the current user exists.  You also just throw away the `profile_name` element completely when you assign `profile_name` to `current_user`, so you'll never get a profile image for anything but the current user on a profile page.

You take in profile_name here, but never use it:

```
   def get(self, profile_name):
        current_user = str(self.user.name)
        profile_name = current_user
```

- You loop over `imgs` but replace the key each time, which means that if you return more than 1 image you can't tell that this has occurred and you overwrite anything but the last image in the query. One thing you should do is add a check to see if `imgs` is even truthy, so you can tell if you got any results whatsoever, that might (though I can't imagine how) explain why your image handler is failing.

Finally, you might check your source to see which image url is actually being requested in the template.

Comment: I would also like to add to this answer that this `self.render('profile.html', profile_name = self.user.name, ....)` can be replaced with `self.render('profile.html',user = self.user)` and the template be adjusted accordingly.